# Quel adverbe utiliser pour qualifier un évènement certain ?

Tags: adverbes, oral, demande-de-mot

En français, l'usage de certains adverbes n'a pas toujours le sens que l'on pourrait y donner.

Par exemple :

> J'irai certainement la voir / J'irai sûrement la voir.

Bien que les mots *certainement* et *sûrement* définissent quelque de chose d'évident ne laissant pas place au hasard, l'usage fait que l'on comprend ces phrases comme :

> J'irai probablement la voir / J'irai sans doute la voir.

---

On pourrait utiliser *assurément* ou *indubitablement*, mais ces mots donnent un sens plus soutenu à la phrase et moins naturel pour du **langage parlé**.

Actuellement, je trouve que la forme la plus naturelle est "*J'irai la voir*", plus simple, mais montrant moins d'incertitude.

**Quel adverbe utiliser en français afin d'appuyer une idée de certitude ?**

Comment: Perhaps it wouldn’t still be considered an adverb when placed at the beginning of an affirmation, but for some reason I think “Certainement, j’irai la voir” goes a bit beyond the notion of “probablement” that might exist with “J’irai certainement la voir.”

Comment: J'irai la voir sans faute.

Comment: On peut remarquer que _sans doute_ signifie qu'il y en a un, sinon on précise _sans_ _**aucun**_ _doute_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne sais pas si l'on peut rester naturel (pas trop formel) en langage parlé sous la contrainte d'ajouter un adverbe. Si l'on prend l'une des (très bonnes) suggestions dans une autre réponse :

> J'irai la voir immanquablement.

Je ne pense pas que cette expression soit fréquente ou naturelle en conversation non-soutenue (mais encore une fois, c'est une très bonne réponse en général).

On peut aussi utiliser les adverbes suivants en langage parlé, ni soutenu, ni trop familier :

> J'irai obligatoirement la voir.
>
> J'irai définitivement la voir.
>
> J'irai inévitablement la voir.
>
> J'irai absolument la voir.
>
> J'irai la voir, absolument. (noter la virgule, construction applicable aux adverbes précédents)

Autres expressions courantes, sans adverbe :

> J'irai la voir quoi qu'il arrive.
>
> Je suis sûr d'aller la voir.
>
> J'irai la voir, c'est sûr.
>
> J'ai bien l'intention d'aller la voir.
>
> Je la verrai à tout prix.
>
> Je vais la voir.
>
> Je vais aller la voir.

Cette dernière expression est intéressante, utilisant le verbe *aller* deux fois, la première fois pour dénoter l'intention, la deuxième fois pour indiquer le mouvement. On sent l'intention un peu plus que dans *je vais la voir* ou *j'irai la voir*.

Answer (score 2):

Comme déjà indiqué dans la question, l'absence d'adverbe joue ce rôle :

> J'irai la voir.

Sinon, une locution adjectivale ou adverbiale est possible :

> J'irai, promis juré, la voir.
>
> J'irai bien sûr la voir.

Comment: Ce qui ne répond pas à la question : *"Quel **adverbe** utiliser en français afin d'appuyer une idée de certitude ?"*. D'autant plus que j'ai déjà précisé cette forme dans ma question : *Actuellement, je trouve que la forme la plus naturelle est "J'irai la voir"*.

Comment: Ah oui, je n'avais pas lu la question jusqu'au bout.

Answer (score 2):

On peut dire :

> J'irai la voir absolument.

ou

> J'irai nécessairement la voir.

ou bien, à la place d'un adverbe :

> De toutes façons, j'irai la voir.

ou

> De toute façon, j'irai la voir.

Comment: @Frank: On peut écrire aussi bien au singulier qu'au pluriel mais il faut accorder ;)

Comment: ok - pas de problème :-)

Answer (score 2):

> J'irai forcément la voir.
>
> (J'irai obligatoirement la voir.)

Ces adverbes introduisent certes l'idée d'une contrainte, mais ça peut être une contrainte que l'on s'impose à soi-même: "j'irai forcément la voir [puisque j'en ai pris la décision et que je compte m'y tenir]".

Sinon, comme l'ont dit les autres, la façon la plus naturelle reste encore de se passer d'adverbe :

> Dans tous les cas, j'irai la voir.
>
> J'irai la voir de toute façon.

Answer (score 2):

> J'irai la voir [immanquablement](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/immanquablement/41671). [à coup sûr]
>  J'irai
>   [invariablement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/invariablement) la voir. [d'une manière qui ne change pas, on peut
>   déduire assurément..]

Comment: Ces propositions sont très bonnes, mais je pensais que la question visait plutôt des expressions naturelles en langage parlé, et pas trop soutenues, ce qui n'est pas vraiment le cas ici. Je ne crois pas que l'on entendrait ces deux phrases en conversation normale.

Comment: @Frank Merci ! DHLF/Rey : « Le dérivé _immanquablement_ [...] est relativement courant. » ; _assurément_ « s'emploie en réponse pour « certainement » [...] » ; _invariablement_ est moins rare que son antonyme ; et _indubitablement_ « est plutôt didactique» . Une affirmation à l'effet que les premiers donnent un sens plus soutenu n'est pas instantanément étayée. Pas plus que l'idée qu'un verbe au futur emporterait une incertitude. Je ne suis lié par l'opinion, a fortiori reposant sur des données partielles, là où l'usage peut varier. Enfin on demande un adverbe en gras, deux fois plutôt qu'une.

Comment: Oui on demande un adverbe, j'ai bien vu. Mais c'est un peu en contradiction avec "langage parlé" et "naturel", qui sont aussi mentionnés dans la question. Il y a un "mais" devant "soutenu" dans la question qui laisse à penser que l'on cherche quelque chose de "plus simple" (quelques lignes après) et la solution sans adverbe est préférée dans l'énoncé du problème :-) mais peu importe. Pour ce qui est de l'usage, on pourrait vérifier les fréquences avec google ngrams. Mais je soutiens que "immanquablement" n'est pas courant _en conversation courante_ :-)

Comment: Une petite recherche rapide sur [google.ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inmanquablement%2C%C3%A0+coup+s%C3%BBr&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cinmanquablement%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%A0%20coup%20s%C3%BBr%3B%2Cc0), "à coup sûr" est 422 fois plus courant que "immanquablement" aujourd'hui, dans les livres du corpus ngrams - bien sûr, cela est à prendre avec des pincettes. Un petit sondage parmi les natifs autour de moi révèle qu'aucun n'utiliserait immanquablement en conversation aujourd'hui. "A coup sûr"? Assurèment :-)

Comment: Mais soit. Pour moi, le futur simple, les finales des mots, les pronoms et bien d'autres choses c'est un peu trop soutenu à mon goût, et le juron est requis dans au moins un exemple : _T'en passe un papier m'en va a voir ; m'en va a voir c'est garanti là ; c't'affaire que m'en va a voir ; m'en va définitivement a voir ; m'en va a voir aussi vra' que j'm'appelle X/que le p'tit Jésus su'a croix y e' là d'vant nous aut' ; m'en va a voir que l'crisse._ Satisfait ? Merci.

Comment: J’aime les options moins soutenues proposées en commentaire! Pour “m'en va définitivement a voir”, je pensais moi-même à «définitivement» pour tenter d’en faire une réponse (car en anglais, «*definitely* would  definitely work»). J’ai pas fait par peur qu’ils soient [«faux amis»](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=definitivement&T3.x=9&T3.y=14&id=1102) **MAIS** [d’après CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9finitivement/adverbe), «définitivement»=«C−Région.(Canada). Certainement, assurément» et donc sont définitivement pas vus comme faux amis partout dans la Francophonie!

Comment: @PapaPoule Bonne observation ! C'est pourquoi j'avais pensé mettre entre parenthèse _et n'en reviendra jamais..._.  Ce sont de vrais amis dans le sens employé en commentaire, au Qc., puisque c'est le calque de _definitely_ en effet... c'est très usuel pour assurément. Quant à _passer un papier_, aussi régional au TLFi à _passer_, un peu comme on voit ailleurs pour l'idée de jurer/promettre/dire, que j'aborde par ailleurs ds. les exemples avec le nom et les références religieuses, mais honnêtement c'est [Fardoche](https://youtu.be/AOgNIh2ZPv8) qui je crois qui m'a appris c'papier-là ! Merci.

Comment: @Frank Il m'aurait fallu expliquer plus gentiment, désolé. Ce qui n'est _pas trop soutenu_ pour vous diffère chez/pour moi (Qc.). Par exemple, a priori _immanquablement_ ne m'est même pas assez soigné pour que je l'utilise à l'écrit. Dans mon usage il est p-ê. dans la même catégorie que _pareillement_, que je n'utilise pas pour retourner la pareille lorsqu'on me souhaite un truc, mais que j'utilise régulièrement pendant le temps des Fêtes. Par ailleurs d'autres propositions me sont d'apparence plus soignée/moins régionale que _immanquablement_ etc. Il prend le tag France à mon avis. Merci.